# Memory efficient conversion between a HashMap and a Vec

Tags: performance, memory-management, collections, rust, out-of-memory

I'm trying to convert a big `HashMap<K, V>` to `Vec<(K, V)>`. The usual way of doing it looks like this:

```
// initialize HashMap
let cap = 50000000;
let mut hm: HashMap<usize, usize> = HashMap::new();
for i in 0..cap {
    hm.insert(i, i);
}
// convert HashMap to Vec
let vec = hm.into_iter().collect::<Vec<(usize, usize)>>();
```

This code does not work well if `HashMap` is big enough - in the beginning of the call to `collect()`, the original `HashMap` will still be in memory and `Vec` will be allocated with the capacity of lower size hint taken from the `Iterator`. This causes an out of memory panic for really big `HashMap`s, even though I should be able to convert between these two types with very little additional memory overhead. So far I have came up with the following solution:

```
// create small vector
let mut vec: Vec<(usize, usize)> = Vec::with_capacity(100);
for i in hm.into_iter() {
    vec.push(i);
    // reserve few megabytes
    if vec.capacity() - vec.len() < 10 {
        vec.reserve_exact(1000000);
    }
}
```

Is there any better (more efficient or more idiomatic) approach to this problem? I am willing to use `unsafe` code if it were to improve performance.

**Edit**
As pointed out `into_iter` does not deallocate during iteration, so the proposed solution does not work as intended. Is there any other way of converting these collections apart from dumping `HashMap` to the file and then reading that file into `Vec`?

Comment: Are you sure your second code has less memory overhead? I don't think that the `IntoIter` iterator will free memory during iteration. Actually it's not *that* easy to do this conversation with little additional memory...

Comment: If do not have enough memory to store both the `HashMap` and the `Vec` at the same time, you may want to switch computer, or restructure your program to be able to work on smaller chunks of work (MapReduce for example). As it is, you have very little headroom: if the problem size rises by 50%, you might very well be OOM with *just* the `HashMap`, and then what are you going to do?

Answer (score 4):

Allocating the exact amount needed up front *is* the memory- and time-efficient solution.

Say you want to create a vector with 100 items. If you were to allocate space for 50 items, when you go to add item 51, two possibilities exist:

1. The allocation can be extended in place and you continue on your merry way.
2. The allocation can not be extended in place, so a new, larger allocation is made. All the data needs to be copied from the previous allocation; likely an O(n) operation. During this copy, both allocations are live, taking up 50 + 100 slots, *more* space than if the original allocation was properly sized.

It's not possible to know which case will happen, so you have to assume the worst.

This is one of the reasons that `Iterator` has the `size_hint` method: knowing how many items to allocate for is more efficient.

On the flip side, the `HashMap` likely stores the data in one big allocation as it's more efficient. This means that it's not possible (or maybe not easy / effective) to move one item out and then decrease the allocation. Even if you could do this, at the beginning of the copy you'd have both the entire `HashMap` and `Vec` allocated.

There are two possibilities I can think of that could improve the situation:

1. If `HashMap` stores the data internally in a `Vec`, then potentially a method could be added to `HashMap` that returns that `Vec` after some last-minute sanitization.
2. Avoid storing the `HashMap` and/or `Vec` at all. For example, if you need to iterate over the data, you don't need to `collect` to a `Vec` first; just iterate over it.

Comment: I think I remember that `HashMap` uses 3 vectors, as coded: (hashes, keys, values). As a result, there is no trivial conversion from `HashMap<usize, usize>` to `Vec<(usize, usize)>`.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you're not satisfied with `Vec`'s implementation of `FromIterator` trait. I don't know if it is reasonable to change it in std. However, you can introduce a wrapper for `Vec` and implement `FromIterator` as you wish:

```
#[derive(Debug)]
struct OptimizedVec<T>(Vec<T>);

impl<T> std::iter::FromIterator<T> for OptimizedVec<T> {
    #[inline]
    fn from_iter<I: IntoIterator<Item = T>>(iter: I) -> OptimizedVec<T> {
        let mut vec = Vec::with_capacity(100);
        for i in iter {
            vec.push(i);
            // reserve few megabytes
            if vec.capacity() - vec.len() < 10 {
                vec.reserve_exact(1000000);
            }
        }
        OptimizedVec(vec)
    }
}

//...
let vec: OptimizedVec<_> = hm.into_iter().collect();
```

The `Vec` value will be accessible as `vec.0`.

Comment: Unless I completely misunderstood something, it's definitely not reasonable to fix it in `std`. A memory optimal implementation would be far slower than the way it is done now. I also doubt that OPs own implementation helps...

Comment: I was planning on wrapping that code in custom struct, but i didn't post it for the sake of simplicity of the question. I understand that `std`s implementation shouldn't be changed as that would have massive timing implications. My use case is rather rare and i was wondering if there was any better way than consecutive `reserve_exact` calls.

Comment: The idea is that you reserve a relatively small chunk of items such that push would not have to reallocate. I will edit the question to avoid false information (I thought that into_iter releases memory as it moves through the iterator).